# ASP.NET Redirect to page if entity has property set globally

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have a fairly simple question about how the best way to globally redirect to a page if a property in an entity has a specific value. For example if you have a simple game and want every user to have a character entity, but before any specific game route can be accessed the character needs to be created (E.g name, gender, etc.). I was thinking you could simply have a property bool (Created/not created) for this.

So more concretely my question is how can I redirect to "Index" in a "CreateCharacter" controller from all pages if the character has the "not created" property but don't do anything otherwise.

I've tried using a custom action filter and registering it as a global filter but it's quite wonky and just generates an infinite loop. Is there any obvious simple solution I'm missing here?

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    using (var dbCtx = new ApplicationDbContext())
    {
        var character = HttpContext.Current.GetCharacter(dbCtx);
        if (character == null)
        {
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
            return;
        }

        if (character.IsCreated)
        {
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
            return;
        }

        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
            new RouteValueDictionary(new {controller = "CreateCharacter", action = "Index"})
            );

        filterContext.Result.ExecuteResult(filterContext.Controller.ControllerContext);
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

If using a custom filter is the whole wrong idea for this, I'd love to learn alternatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting an infinite loop because you are applying the same logic even if the user goes to the `Index` action of your `CreateCharacter` controller.

Your approach seems to me very reasonable, simply adjust your code to not redirect the user if the current action is exactly the destination:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    var actionName = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName;
    var controllerName = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName

    if(controllerName == "CreateCharacter" && actionName == "Index")
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        return;
    }

    using (var dbCtx = new ApplicationDbContext())
    {
        var character = HttpContext.Current.GetCharacter(dbCtx);
        if (character == null)
        {
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
            return;
        }

        if (character.IsCreated)
        {
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
            return;
        }

        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
            new RouteValueDictionary(new {controller = "CreateCharacter", action = "Index"})
            );

        filterContext.Result.ExecuteResult(filterContext.Controller.ControllerContext);
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```